# Why doesn't my routing work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Im trying to set up an alternative route on my application...

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                "x", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{datetime}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", datetime = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

I have the action...

```
public ActionResult GetBlogsByMonth(string datetime)
        {
            if (datetime!= null)
            {
                IList<BlogModel> blogs = (IList<BlogModel>)manager.GetBlogsInMonth(DateTime.Parse(datetime)).ToList();
                return View(blogs);
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

But when I put the debugger on the action the datetime is always null... :-(

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to define a route like this: `{controller}/{action}/{year}/{month}` and the method like this: `GetBlogsByMonth(string year, string month)` .....

Answer (score 1):

Probably, your request has been caught by another route. Make sure to put your route at the top when you are registering them.

For example, if you are using this route with the default one, the default one will catch the request, not your custom route if you reference them in the following order:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);


routes.MapRoute(
    "x", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{datetime}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", datetime = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

As for the solution, as @Darin suggested, you need to define a constraint because if you put your custom one in front, this time the default one will never be hit.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "x", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{datetime}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", datetime = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
    new { datetime = @"^(19|20)\d\d([- /.])(0[1-9]|1[012])\2(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

The below URLs will be caught by your custom route:

> /Poo/Bar/2011-11-31
>
> /Poo/Bar/2011-01-04
>
> /Poo/Bar/2011-01-04

You can change the RegEx for your needs.

Comment: If you inverse the order then the default route will never be hit because those 2 routes actually represent exactly the same pattern. You will need to define route constraints if you want to disambiguate them.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov you are right. But either case his custom one needs to be referenced before the default one.

Comment: yes this is true. I was just wondering if you could provide an example that will answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

When constructing a link to your action you can use a RouteLink instead of an ActionLink. With the RouteLink you can pass a named route name to force the right route is chosen to construct the link. For your example the link should look somehow like this:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Blog Posts...", "x", new { controller="Blog", action="GetBlogsByMonth" datetime = THEDATETIME })
```

Hint: You can use the DateTime type in your action as parameter instead of a String type so you can avoid the unnecessary call to DateTime.Parse